# MySQL deleting lots of rows by id - where in or loop over each row in transaction

Tags: mysql, php, transaction, delete

I have a delete query which is potentially going to delete tens of thousands of rows.

Currently it's taking quite a long time in the more extreme case (over 100000 rows to delete) using this:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?...)
```

However, I was wondering whether it might be better to create a transaction and use php to loop through each of the deletes.

Something like...

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id=?;
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id=?;
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id=?;
.....
COMMIT;
```

I hope this makes sense... I'm not the best at using the correct terminology.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the list of ids?  If you got them from another table, then do a [multi-table DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html).  This would be best, except that it stills suffers from #1, below.

1. A single delete with 100K rows will take a long time because that is an awfully large number of things to save for possible ROLLBACK.
2. Deleting one row at a time is awfully slow if each is a separate transaction (autocommit=ON).
3. Deleting individual rows in a huge transaction has the same ROLLBACK issue, plus the overhead of doing separate commands (extra parsing, roundtrips, etc).

Here's another thought:  Use PHP, but gather 1000 ids at a time.  That is:

```
SET autocommit=1;
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN (... 1000 ids ...);
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN (... 1000 ids ...);
...
```

If convenient, sort the 100K ids before starting this; that will help the "locality" a bit.  This breaking up of the ids softens the negative issues mentioned above.

Not quite the same: [*Blog on Big Deletes*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/big-deletes/) , but it might give you some more insight and ideas.  (It discusses, among other things, the impact on Replication, and a benefit of using `PARTITION`.)